# Authentication in ASP.NET using FormsAuthentication

Tags: asp.net

I am using `FormsAuthentication` and `ASP.NET Memberships and Roles` in my ASP.NET project. I have some aspx files which can be viewed / accessed by only authenticated users. I think I can do this using one of the following two ways.

1. Configuring the web.config file. Allow users with roles 'admin' and 'members' to access those apsx files, and deny all other anonymous users.
2. In page_load events of those apsx files, just checking whether the curent user is authenticated or not using `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`

I am wondering whether these two approaches are equivalent or not for apsx files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not equivalent. Method 1. gives access only to the "admin" and "members" roles. If you add another role, they won't have access. Method 2 lets any signed in user access the data.

I think that the preferred way is to organize the aspx files in directories depending on what roles should access them. Then configure access on the directories in web.config.

Comment: For method 2, I can check whether the user has the role 'admin' or 'members' using HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole. Now is it equivalent to Method 1?

Comment: Yes, checking `HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole` would make those methods equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

As others mention, this is not equivalent. However, even if you modify "2." to check roles, this is worse approach as you introduce a custom code to handle something which can easily be handled in a standard way.

Consider also yet another approach, where you create a separate **folder**, put your restricted pages there and create an auxiliary `web.config` to contain:

```
...
<system.web>
   <authorization>   
       <allow roles="admin,members" />
       <deny users="*" />
   </authorization>   
</system.web>
```

This way you require authorization to all resources in the folder, pages, styles, images.

Answer (score 0):

Hello you must distinct between Authentification and Authorization

1. "HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated" is : Authentification
2. "Allow users with roles 'admin' and 'members'" is : authorization, after authentification we execute authorization

You can read this article : http://www.duke.edu/~rob/kerberos/authvauth.html

Authentication is the mechanism whereby systems may securely identify their users. Authentication systems provide an answers to the questions:

```
Who is the user?
Is the user really who he/she represents himself to be?
```

Authorization systems provide answers to the questions:

```
Is user X authorized to access resource R?
Is user X authorized to perform operation P?
Is user X authorized to perform operation P on resource R?
```